# Mock Elastic Search response in.Net

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have Elastic Search Nest library code and need to mock the response i am getting from elastic search index.

```
var obj = service.Search<TestDocument>(new student().Query());
var Name= obj.Aggs.Terms("Name");
```

For Testing :
I am creating the Nest object after doing quick watch but facing issue -**Aggregations** - is a internal protected property and i am not able to set this value.

```
                           new Nest.KeyedBucket<object>
                           {   
                               Key="XYZ school",
                               KeyAsString=null,
                               Aggregations=new Dictionary<string, IAggregationContainer>{}
                           }
```

Please suggest solution or any other approach i can use to mock elastic search nest object .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you *really* want to stub the response from the client, you could do something like the following with Moq

```cs
var client = new Mock<IElasticClient>();

var searchResponse = new Mock<ISearchResponse<object>>();

var aggregations = new AggregateDictionary(new Dictionary<string, IAggregate> {
    ["Name"] = new BucketAggregate
    {
        Items = new List<KeyedBucket<object>>
        {
            new Nest.KeyedBucket<object>(new Dictionary<string, IAggregate>())
            {
                Key = "XYZ school",
                KeyAsString = null,
                DocCount = 5
            }
        }.AsReadOnly()
    }
});

searchResponse.Setup(s => s.Aggregations).Returns(aggregations);

client.Setup(c => c.Search<object>(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<object>, ISearchRequest>>()))
    .Returns(searchResponse.Object);

var response = client.Object.Search<object>(s => s);

var terms = response.Aggregations.Terms("Name");
```

Another way would be to use the [`InMemoryConnection` and return known JSON in response to a request.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/modifying-default-connection.html#_using_inmemoryconnection).

For testing purposes however, it may be better to have an instance of Elasticsearch running, and perform integration tests against it. Take a look at [Elastic.Xunit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-abstractions) which provides an easy way to spin up an Elasticsearch cluster for testing purposes. This is used by the client in integration tests.

You can get Elastic.Xunit from [the Appveyor feed](https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/elasticsearch-net-abstractions/packages).