# Mock elasticsearch nested buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, xunit

I'm trying to mock elasticsearch nested aggregation object with the following structure. I did something as described at the attached link, but couldn't do it for nested object:
[Mock Elastic Search response in.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969724/mock-elastic-search-response-in-net)

Here is the real elastic object I've been tying to mock.

```
var obj= new AggregationDictionary
            {
               {
                    "key1",new TermsAggregation("key1")
                    {
                        Field="1234",                         
                        Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary
                        {
                           "top",new TopHitsAggregation("top")
                                {
                                    Size =10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                   }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with my attempts to mock the Elasticsearch object, I came up with the following solutions:

1. Using [in memory connection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/modifying-default-connection.html#_using_inmemoryconnection)

   Elasticsearch (using nest client) documentation will teach you how to "Inject" your desired response in advance. Now you can map the response to your type-safe object without creating a connection to Elasticsearch. I recommend to use this technique on integration test and not Unit test.
2. For unit test, the best option is to abstract your services layer with an interface and totally ignore from Elasticsearch engine.

   Just override services method with your mock object. I use "Moq" and response what ever you want, for example:

   ```
   mockObj= new Mock<IClientRepository>()
   mockObj.Setup(x => x.GetData()).Return("put your response here");
   ```